# How to do LINQ left joins on 2 predicates to 2 tables?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, .net-core

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.HelloID = B.HelloID 
LEFT JOIN C ON A.BusyID = C.BusyID AND B.MemID = C.MemID
```

I've tried the following:

```
var list = from A in this.A
           join B in this.B
              on A.HelloID equals B.HelloID into bgj
           from subb in bgj.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join C in this.C
              on B.MemID equals C.MemID into cgj
           from subc in cgj.DefaultIfEmpty()
              on A.BusyID equals C.BusyID into cgj2
           from subc2 in cgj2.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

but this doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: For one, it should be `.DefaultIfEmpty()` not `.DefaultIfempty`

Comment: good call! Let me add that in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var list = from A in this.A
           join B in this.B
              on A.HelloID equals B.HelloID into bgj
           from subb in bgj.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join C in this.C
             on new { colA = A.BusyID, colB = B.MemID }  equals new { colA = C.BusyID, colB = C.MemID } into cgj
           from subc in cgj.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var list = from A in this.A
           join B in this.B
              on A.HelloID equals B.HelloID into bgj
           from B in bgj.DefaultIfEmpty()
           join C in this.C
              on A.BusyId equals C.BusyId into cgj
           from C in cgj.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where B.MemID == C.MemID
```

You should clarify your question about MemID and BusyId. If they can be null. In this case the last line could be like this:

```
where (B.MemID==null || B.MemID == C.MemID )

//Or 

where ((B.MemID==null && C.MemID==null)  || (B.MemID == C.MemID ))
```

Comment: this kind of causes C.MemID to be mandatory and become an inner join instead of a left join?